# Site collection 404 error after a while of doing nothing

Tags: 2013, site, 404, collection

I have a newly created SP 2013 Foundation install. It has three site collections, (`//copv-shrpt-02` , `//copv-shrpt-02/sites/ar` , `//copv-shrpt-02/sites/ap` (`http:` omitted)) in three separate databases.

After more than a day of working ok, all of a sudden, I keep getting 404 errors trying to access the non root site collections, `../sites/ar` & `../sites/ap`. The root collection works fine.

No number of application pool recycling, server reboots or cleaning of config cache will bring them back. Since it's a new empty install I removed the site collections and content databases and re-created. And it was fine for a while. But then it happened again. It was just after an `IISReset`, not sure if that was just a coincident.

The only thing that didn't go right with the initial install was that both those site collections ended up in the root site collection's content database. So I deleted them and re-created them again, having only the corresponding content databases online to get them assigned as desired.

Digging through the ULS logs at the time of fail I found this section. I'm not quite sure of how to interpret it:

> 12/17/2015 10:36:13.91     w3wp.exe (0x0E3C)                           0x079C  SharePoint Foundation           General                         af71    Medium      HTTP Request method: GET    71364c9d-4696-20ed-7a84-1c65ecb623b5
>   12/17/2015 10:36:13.91  w3wp.exe (0x0E3C)                           0x079C  SharePoint Foundation           General                         af75    Medium      Overridden HTTP request method: GET 71364c9d-4696-20ed-7a84-1c65ecb623b5
>   12/17/2015 10:36:13.91  w3wp.exe (0x0E3C)                           0x079C  SharePoint Foundation           General                         af74    Medium      HTTP request URL: /sites/ap/    71364c9d-4696-20ed-7a84-1c65ecb623b5
>   12/17/2015 10:36:14.45  w3wp.exe (0x0E3C)                           0x0E94  SharePoint Foundation           DistributedCache                ah24w   Unexpected  Unexpected Exception in SPDistributedCachePointerWrapper::InitializeDataCacheFactory for usage 'DistributedLogonTokenCache' - Exception 'Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching.DataCacheException: ErrorCode:SubStatus:The request timed out.. Additional Information : The client was trying to communicate with the server : net.tcp://COPV-SHRPT-02:22233     at Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching.DataCache.ThrowException(ResponseBody respBody, RequestBody reqBody)     at Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching.DataCacheFactory.GetCacheProperties(RequestBody request, IClientChannel channel)     at Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching.DataCacheFactory.GetCache(String cacheName)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.DistributedCaching.SPDistributedCachePointerWrapper.InitializeDataCacheFactory()'.
>   12/17/2015 10:36:14.46  w3wp.exe (0x0E3C)                           0x0E94  SharePoint Foundation           DistributedCache                air4g   Monitorable Token Cache: Failed to initialize SPDistributedSecurityTokenCache  Exception: 'Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching.DataCacheException: ErrorCode:SubStatus:The request timed out.. Additional Information : The client was trying to communicate with the server : net.tcp://COPV-SHRPT-02:22233     at Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching.DataCache.ThrowException(ResponseBody respBody, RequestBody reqBody)     at Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching.DataCacheFactory.GetCacheProperties(RequestBody request, IClientChannel channel)     at Microsoft.ApplicationServer.Caching.DataCacheFactory.GetCache(String cacheName)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.DistributedCaching.SPDistributedCachePointerWrapper.InitializeDataCacheFactory()     at Microsoft.SharePoint.DistributedCaching.SPDistributed...
>   12/17/2015 10:36:14.46* w3wp.exe (0x0E3C)                           0x0E94  SharePoint Foundation           DistributedCache                air4g   Monitorable ...Cache..ctor(String name, TimeSpan timeToLive, SPDistributedCacheContainerType containerType, Boolean encryptData)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.IdentityModel.SPDistributedSecurityTokenCache..ctor(String name, TimeSpan timeToLive, SPDistributedCacheContainerType containerType, Boolean encrptyData, TimeSpan minimumTokenExpirationWindow)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.IdentityModel.SPDistributedSecurityTokenCacheInitializer.Init(Object state)'.
>   12/17/2015 10:36:15.17  OWSTIMER.EXE (0x059C)                       0x0600  SharePoint Foundation           Monitoring                      nasq    Medium      Entering monitored scope (Timer Job job-upgrade-sites). Parent No   0e9dca68-53e1-4503-a4b3-86159f834bba
>   12/17/2015 10:36:15.17  OWSTIMER.EXE (0x059C)                       0x0600  SharePoint Foundation           Logging Correlation Data        xmnv    Medium      Name=Timer Job job-upgrade-sites    74364c9d-265c-20ed-7a84-159f928ed4b7
>   12/17/2015 10:36:15.17  OWSTIMER.EXE (0x059C)                       0x0600  SharePoint Foundation           Monitoring                      b4ly    Medium      Leaving Monitored Scope (Timer Job job-upgrade-sites). Execution Time=9.67902345130456  74364c9d-265c-20ed-7a84-159f928ed4b7
>   12/17/2015 10:36:15.18  OWSTIMER.EXE (0x059C)                       0x0600  SharePoint Foundation           Monitoring                      nasq    Medium      Entering monitored scope (Timer Job job-upgrade-sites). Parent No   0e9dca68-53e1-4503-a4b3-86159f834bba
>   12/17/2015 10:36:15.18  OWSTIMER.EXE (0x059C)                       0x0600  SharePoint Foundation           Logging Correlation Data        xmnv    Medium      Name=Timer Job job-upgrade-sites    74364c9d-165d-20ed-7a84-14ceef8e7202
>   12/17/2015 10:36:15.18  OWSTIMER.EXE (0x059C)                       0x0600  SharePoint Foundation           Monitoring                      b4ly    Medium      Leaving Monitored Scope (Timer Job job-upgrade-sites). Execution Time=6.73856593505599  74364c9d-165d-20ed-7a84-14ceef8e7202
>   12/17/2015 10:36:15.18  OWSTIMER.EXE (0x059C)                       0x0600  SharePoint Foundation           Monitoring                      nasq    Medium      Entering monitored scope (Timer Job job-upgrade-sites). Parent No   0e9dca68-53e1-4503-a4b3-86159f834bba
>   12/17/2015 10:36:15.18  OWSTIMER.EXE (0x059C)                       0x0600  SharePoint Foundation           Logging Correlation Data        xmnv    Medium      Name=Timer Job job-upgrade-sites    74364c9d-165d-20ed-7a84-16c6b0cb0a17
>   12/17/2015 10:36:15.20  OWSTIMER.EXE (0x059C)                       0x0600  SharePoint Foundation           Monitoring                      b4ly    Medium      Leaving Monitored Scope (Timer Job job-upgrade-sites). Execution Time=8.42949313390389  74364c9d-165d-20ed-7a84-16c6b0cb0a17
>   12/17/2015 10:36:15.20  w3wp.exe (0x0E3C)                           0x079C  SharePoint Foundation           Files                           aise3   Medium      Failure when fetching document. 0x80070002  71364c9d-4696-20ed-7a84-1c65ecb623b5
>   12/17/2015 10:36:15.20  w3wp.exe (0x0E3C)                           0x079C  SharePoint Foundation           Monitoring                      b4ly    High        Leaving Monitored Scope (SPSqlClient). Execution Time=1168.48621822047  71364c9d-4696-20ed-7a84-1c65ecb623b5
>   12/17/2015 10:36:15.27  w3wp.exe (0x0E3C)                           0x0BFC  SharePoint Foundation           Asp Runtime                     aj1kp   High        [Forced due to logging gap, Original Level: Verbose] SPRequestModule.PreSendRequestHeaders  71364c9d-4696-20ed-7a84-1c65ecb623b5
>   12/17/2015 10:36:15.27  w3wp.exe (0x0E3C)                           0x0BFC  SharePoint Foundation           Micro Trace                     uls4    Medium      Micro Trace Tags: 0 ajjub,0 nasq,47 agb9s,51 ajy5h,0 ajy5i,0 ajy5h,0 ajy5i,0 ajyxg,0 ajyxh,0 ajy5h,0 ajy5i,0 ajy5h,0 ajy5i,0 ajyxg,0 ajyxh,0 ajxmf,0 ajy5h,0 ajy5i,0 ajy5h,0 ajy5i,0 ajxmx,0 ajy5h,0 ajy5i,0 ajy5h,0 ajy5i,0 ajxmk,1558 b4ly,4 ejq6,281 air4a,0 air4b,4 air4a,0 air4b,942 aeayb,6032 b4ly,19 erv2,52 erv3,917 air36,0 air37,4 b4ly,2 agb9s,34 b4ly,2 b4ly,55 8dzw,0 8dzx    71364c9d-4696-20ed-7a84-1c65ecb623b5

I'm considering reinstalling but wanted to get a 2nd opinion on this.

Comment: Something must have been done. Things don't just stop working. Do the site collection DBs still exist? Have you tried accessing the site collections from a different computer or using the system account (aka farm account)?

Comment: Correct me if I am wrong but I thought all subsites have to be in the same content DB as they are in the same web application.

Comment: You can have multiple content databases bound to a single webapplication. Different Site Collections can be spread across those content databases. Subwebs of a site collections all are bound to the same content database though @Roland

Answer (score 1):

Can you try if a `Use-CacheCluster` command helps here?

Or, also, try steps taken from http://spinternals.blogspot.fr/2014/10/sharepoint-2013-distributed-cache-there.html:

1. At the SharePoint Management Shell command prompt, run the following Command `stop-spdistributedcacheserviceinstance -gracefull` on all cache hosts.
2. At the SharePoint Management Shell command prompt, run the following command `remove-spdistributedcacheserviceinstance` on all cache hosts.
3. Execute the SharePoint Products Configuration Wizard on all SharePoint servers.
4. At the SharePoint Management Shell command prompt, run the following Command `add-spdistributedcacheserviceinstance` on all cache hosts.

Comment: I will if breaks again. I recreated the site collections a 2nd time to try something else that was suggested.

Comment: Someone suggested that having the main site in a site collection sitting without a template for a long time could cause this to happen. I doesn't make sense to me why. But that's exactly how both my site collections main sites were created. So this time I created one with and one without. But I agree, something having gotten  out of order with the cache makes more sense.

Comment: Hum, it may be because this means your root site collection is not accessible. I know this is a real problem for the search crawler (since it only tries to reach the Data Web service at the Web app root). Maybe this also breaks the distributed cache.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. Do you mean just not accessible to the crawler or not accessible when browsing to the site?

Comment: I just checked our dev environment. It has the same cache error intermittently. But is not dropping off the two site collections